# Firefox sometimes doesn't load image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas element in [this pen](http://codepen.io/vahidseo/pen/vdDLy). Sometimes when I view it in Firefox, everything's alright, but other times, it doesn't load the image. What could be wrong? Chrome is working good.

In order to use it:

```
var txt = new txtImg (/*params*/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use your image before it's fully loaded.

The browser will start loading your image (on img.src) and immediately continue onto the next code while it simultaneously loads the image.

Use the img.onload callback to wait for your image to fully load.

```
var txt;
var img = document.createElement ( 'img' );
img.onload=function(){
    txt = new txtImg ( img, "ABCDEF...long text shortened", 10 );
    document.body.style.background = "rgb(132, 162, 255)";
}
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...long text shortened";
```

Comment: Thanks. The src should go before the onload event, though.